Most efficient way to recompute matrix cost after swapping columns
I work with regular matrices $M \in \mathbb N^{n\times n}$ with $n > 1$.
My cost function is:
$$\text{Cost} = \sum_{i=1, j>i}^n M_{ij}$$
Hence, we only consider the superior triangle, diagonal excluded.
I also have a permutation vector $\pi$ such that $\forall i,j \in [1, n]$:
$$M'_{ij} = M_{\pi(i)\pi(j)}$$
My question is: how to compute the cost of $M'$ knowing the one of $M$ as efficiently as possible, considering that only the elements $k$ and $l$ of $\pi$ were exchanged? By "efficiently" I mean that a program would find the right cost in an optimal time.
The basic cost calculation is the following:
for (i=0; i < n; i++)
    for (j=i+1; j < n; j++)
        cost += M[pi(i)][pi(j)];

By "swap", I mean that for $1 \le k, l \le n$ and $k \neq l$:
$$\pi'(k) = \pi(l) \text{ and } \pi'(l) = \pi(k)$$
An exchange as described above does not change every element of $M$. So how should I recompute the cost of $M'$ after each exchange $(k, l)$?
NB: this question comes into the context of an heuristic optimisation problem, where a very large amount of exchanges are considered in $\pi$ so that an maximal cost can be found for $M$.
